# Journey fires on Cloud Pages subscription, but not Imports

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have a Journey that successfully fires each hour and deploys a **WELCOME** email to those who subscribed via our **Cloud Page sign-up form**... However, no new records that are added via import/query of a shared master DE are entering the Journey at all -- in fact, I don't believe they are being evaluated for entry either.

The query adds new records to the respective DE based on data within that shared DE.  The "respective DE" in this situation is the `FIRE EVENT` DE that is working when new sign-ups occur via the Cloud Page.

I've tried to troubleshoot the query, but everything checks out.

Is it possible that imports into a DE are not considered as part of a `FIRE EVENT`?

Comment: anyone? anyone?  bueller?  bueller?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using CloudPages as the Entry Event which means the journey will only evaluate that Smart Capture form in your CloudPage.

Instead of using Smart Capture, you should use the AMPscript function of [UpsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm) in the CloudPage. This will add records from the sign-up form into your data extension. Then you can have your existing import and query also writing to this same data extension.

In Journey Builder, instead of a CloudPages entry event use that Data Extension as the entry event. When new records get added to that Data Extension via Upsert from your CloudPage, import, or query, those contacts will be evaluated and injected into your journey.

More on Entry Sources here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_entry_sources.htm&type=5

More on AMPscript here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/index.htm